# Create a schortcut for Keyboard Key + Scroll

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I want to map the action `ctrl+shift+tab + scroll` to volume up/down. How can I achieve this?

I know that `ctrl + scroll` maps to zoom in/out by default. Surely, there must be a way to create such a custom shortcut no?

(I am running kde plasma 5.14.5)

Answer (score 1):

As far as my reseach went, I wasn't able to find any elegant solution to the problem. I hacked a very crude python script that does the job poorly... I'm sorry.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

kbd = Controller()

COMBINATIONS = [{keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.Key.shift}]

current = set()

def execute():
    with mouse.Listener(on_scroll=on_mscroll) as listener:
        listener.join()

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            # this executes only once and then it looses the keycombination
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        try:
            current.remove(key)
        except KeyError:
            pass

def on_mscroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    if dy < 0:
        # this can be changed to the appropriate command to change the volume
        # like pactl
        call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "5%-"],stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    else:
        call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "5%+"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The problem with this is that you need to press `ctrl` + `shift` + scoll up/down and then RE-PRESS `shift` to toggle the action again. I mean it's annyong. Also this does not block the scroll, so you might want to scroll on a neutral place (like a sidebar).

This uses `pynput` but I hope that won't be a problem